# Relative paths with NCover and MSTest.exe

Tags: mstest, relative-path, ncover

I know this is stupid, but I can't figure it out. In our solution, we specify the relative paths to a file one of our tests needs as -

../../../TestSuite/IniTestFiles/LocalRedir1.xml

Now, this works fine when running the testing out of VS with MSTest.exe. However, in NCover all of the tests fail. Does anyone know how I can go about fixing this? I can't move the file's location. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the working path of NCover //w.

This way the ../.. will be relative to that folder.

You may also contact support

Joe Feser
NCover